# Akka "Best Effort Retry" with RxJava

Tags: akka, rx-java

I am curious about using RxJava to implement best effort retry in Akka, without Persistent Actors. The idea is to use Rx's `retry` method to keep asking until a response is received from the destination actor.

Other examples of this is hard to find. Are there any Akka gurus out there that could verify this implementation, or point me to a better solution?

Example:

```
public class RxWithAkka {

    private final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

    public static final Timeout TIMEOUT = Timeout.apply(10, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    private final ActorRef actor;
    private final ActorSystem actorSystem;

    public RxWithAkka(ActorSystem actorSystem) {
        this.actorSystem = actorSystem;
        this.actor = actorSystem.actorOf(Props.create(MyActor.class));
    }

    public Observable<Object> ping() {
        return createObservable()
                .doOnError(t -> LOGGER.warn(t.getMessage()))
                .retry();
    }

    Observable<Object> createObservable() {
        return Observable.create(subscriber -> {
            LOGGER.info("Send ping");
            Patterns.ask(actor, "ping", TIMEOUT)
                    .onComplete(new OnComplete<Object>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(Throwable failure, Object success) throws Throwable {
                            if (success != null) {
                                subscriber.onNext(success);
                                subscriber.onCompleted();
                            } else {
                                subscriber.onError(failure);
                            }
                        }
                    }, actorSystem.dispatcher());
        });
    }
}
```

Example actor to demonstrate message not received and timeout:

```
public class MyActor extends UntypedActor {

        private int counter = 0;

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Object message) throws Exception {
            switch (counter++) {
                case 0:
                    // ignore message
                    break;
                case 1:
                    // timeout
                    Thread.sleep(200);
                    break;
                default:
                    getSender().tell("pong", getSelf());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Test:

```
public class RxWithAkkaTest {

    @Test
    public void testIt() throws Exception {
        ActorSystem system = ActorSystem.create("system");
        RxWithAkka example = new RxWithAkka(system);
        String res = (String) example.ping().toBlocking().first();
        assertThat(res).isEqualTo("pong");
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe obvious but I’ll say it anyway: without Persistence it will not actually be at-least-once, it will be “best effort retry”. Not saying that that is bad, your use-case might be completely fine with that, just trying to keep the terminology straight.

Answer (score 1):

In RxJava, you can use the `timeout` operator in conjunction with `retry`.